# Background images not rendering correctly and others dont appear on Ipad

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, html, ipad-2

Hi im currently developing this site:

http://remedia-solutions.com/clientes/0039_kiplingmexico/demo2/

Actually is works perfectly on Mac and on PC browsers, the problem here is when i go into Safari Ipad some background images dont show at all and the others have scale problems.

So ill show you my currently CSS see if i can get any help im trying to investigate at the moment since im new on Ipad.

This is my css for IPAD(theres another one for PC and mac):

```
#fondo1{
    background-image: url("images/imagesbackground/BACKGROUND-INICIO.jpg");
    background-position: top center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1440px 950px;
    -webkit-background-size: 1440px 950px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block; 
}
#fondo1int{
    background-image: url("images/INICIO.png");
    background-position: center center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
    -moz-background-size: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    display: block; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#fondo2{
    background-image: url("images/imagesbackground/BACKGROUND-HISTORIA.jpg");
    background-position: top center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1440px 950px;
    -moz-background-size: 1440px 950px;
    -webkit-background-size: 1440px 950px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

#fondo2int{
    background-image: url("images/BACKGTOUND-TEXTO-HISTORIA.png");
    background-position: center center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
    -moz-background-size: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

And this is my jquery to calculate the window height and width:

```
$("#todoini,#todohistoria , #todocoleccion , #todocuidados, #todosucursales,#todocontacto").css('height', $(window).height());
$("#todoini, #todohistoria , #todocoleccion , #todocuidados, #todosucursales,#todocontacto").css('width', $(window).width());
$("#navimage").css('margin-left', $(window).width() / 2 - 140);
$("#navimage").css('margin-top', $(window).height() -140);
$("#contenidoimagen , #contenidoimagen2 , #contenidoimagen3 , #contenidoimagen4, #contenidoimagen5,#contenidoimagen6").css('width', $(window).width());
$("#contenidoimagen, #contenidoimagen2 ,#contenidoimagen3 , #contenidoimagen4 , #contenidoimagen5,#contenidoimagen6").css('height', $(window).height());
$("#todo").css('width', $("#todoini").width() + $("#todohistoria").width() + $("#todocoleccion").width() + $("#todocuidados").width() + $("#todosucursales").width() + $("#todocontacto").width());
$("#todoini , #todohistoria, #todocoleccion, #todocuidados, #todosucursales, #todocontacto").css('float', 'left');
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#todoini,#todohistoria , #todocoleccion , #todocuidados, #todosucursales, #todocontacto ").css('height', $(window).height());
    $("#todoini,#todohistoria , #todocoleccion , #todocuidados, #todosucursales, #todocontacto").css('width', $(window).width());
    $("#contenidoimagen , #contenidoimagen2 , #contenidoimagen3 , #contenidoimagen4, #contenidoimagen5 , #contenidoimagen6").css('width', $(window).width());
    $("#todo").css('width', $("#todoini").width() + $("#todohistoria").width() + $("#todocoleccion").width() + $("#todocuidados").width() + $("#todosucursales").width() + $("#todocontacto").width());
});
$(window).trigger('resize')
```

So the background container always have a width and a height set.

Any ideas?

Quick edit if i use background-size: Cover it does show but the image is hella big :/

Answer (score 0):

Solutions was to setup a width and height for each background.

```
#fondo1{
    background:  url("images/imagesbackground/BACKGROUND-INICIO.jpg");
    background-position:    top center;
    background-repeat:      no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size:    1024px 768px !important;
    position:absolute;
    width:1024px !important;
    height:768px !important;



}
#fondo1int{
    background-image: url("images/INICIO-OTONO.png") !important;
    background-position:    center center;
    background-attachment: initial; 
    background-repeat:      no-repeat;
    background-size:    800px 400px !important;
    position:absolute;
    width:1024px !important;
    height:768px !important;



}
```